# Linux; how to loop over files and output the names of files and output of the command in one line

Tags: linux, bash

I have a command that takes the names of the files from my name.txt file and than loop over the files and do the script.sh. My output must be the name of the file, followed by the output of the script.sh, but it does not work. What is wrong with my command?

```
cat name.txt |while read name ; do cov='script.sh $name' ; echo $name $cov ; done
```

script.sh works fine if I run it individually. I assume that the problem is in de line with do cov='etc', but I cannot figure out what is wrong. I also tried double quotes "etc", did not work either.

Comment: whats the content of `script.sh` ?

Comment: use `xargs`. It will be do the two jobs: interpreting the names, and executing the script

Comment: 'script.sh $name' does not execute the script. for this use back quote
doc cov=`script.sh $name`

Comment: `cov="$(script.sh $name)"` instead of `cov='script.sh $name'`. Also prefer `while read name; do ... ; done <file` to `cat file | while read name; do ... ; done`

Comment: @NishanthSpShetty `$(...)` subshell are the more modern equivalent to back-ticks (in particular they can be nested), and also have the advantage not to mess with markdown formatting ;) if you need to write backticks in markdown, use double backticks to enclose the script part of your text, e.g. ``here are `ticks` !``

Comment: @Aaron yeah, that will work too. And thank you for the suggestions on ```

Comment: @Aaron; yes that works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you shoule use backtick `` quotes or $() my preferred **AND** double-quotes

like this **cov="$(script.sh $name)"**

$(command) makes *command* run and its output used as input for cov=
and double-quotes ensure that **all** output of *command* will be used for cov= (and not separated by whitespace and misinterpreted)